# Is a variable declared in a loop body preserved during iterations?

Tags: c, loops, scope, variable-declaration

Consider a loop in C which declares a character array in the loop's body. At each iteration, a character of array is modified until the end is reached. At the end, the variable is printed. The description would expand to the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (;;) {/* same as: while(1) { */
        char x[5];
        x[i] = '0' + i;
        if (++i == 4) {
            x[i] = '\0'; /* terminate string with null byte */
            printf("%s\n", x);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Many may expect `0123` as output. But for some reason GCC 4.7 does not do that when compiling with optimization enabled (`-O1` and higher). It instead puts random data in the first bytes of the character array, which becomes:

```
| 0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4   |
|     RANDOM     | '3' | '\0' |
```

I think that this is logical behaviour from the language point of view: automatic variables are gone after a block is terminated, so the above "random" behaviour should be expected.

What should be the correct behaviour? **I know that moving the declaration of `x` outside the loop "fixes" it, but that does not say anything about the behaviour of this snippet**. The real-world problem is a [bug in Netfilter](http://bugzilla.netfilter.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774).

Comment: x[i] = '0' + i; 
what will happen in this line when the loop runs for the 1st time? Because at this time i = 0 and the equivalent line which be executed is x[0] = '0' + 0. So we want to store 00 in x[0]. I read C a long ago, so dont remember how exactly character array works. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Rain `'0' + 0` is just `'0'`, `'0' + 2` is `'2'`, that part is fine. It's just the unspecified contents of the array due to the scope that's problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then its obvious that we will have random value for the 1st 3 characters as in the last iteration the equivalent line which will execute is x[3] = 3 and we dont assign anything for x[0], x[1] and x[2]. So we will always have the result as you said in the question.

Comment: @Rain The evil part is that there's a high probability that the result will indeed be an array `{ '0', '1', '2', '3', '\0' }` printed. It's quite natural for the compiler to place the array in the same spot each iteration, and since it's not initialised, why should it not contain the data written in the previous iterations? I got 0123 printed out for all optimisation levels.

Comment: :) Yes you are getting the output because of the help from compiler.. But when we dont assign any value we should get garbage. But the correct approach is to declare the array outside the loop.

Comment: @Rain Do you know what you are talking about? Of course the output depends on the compiler, the garbage is a result of the generated instructions that skips some assignments because the behaviour is undefined anyway. The question wasn't about declaring the array outside the loop, but whether the observerd behaviour with GCC 4.7 was correct or not.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Actually, I think it's not undefined behaviour (unless `char` has one trap representation and one of the array elements happens to be that). The values of the array elements are unspecified, so the output is undetermined, but reading unspecified values doesn't make the behaviour undefined.

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right, I was mixing two terms up. Thanks for the correction, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the array is declared inside the scope of loop's body, you can think of it as of a new array being allocated in the automatic storage area for each loop iteration. The content of that unititialized array is undefined, except for the character at the index to which you have assigned during the current iteration, so what you see there is indeterminate value:

> **C99 standard, section 6.7.8**: If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate

When optimization is turned off, the array lands in the same spot in the automatic storage, so your program gets lucky; however, this is by no means guaranteed.

Move the array to outside the loop, like this:

```
int i = 0;
char x[5];
for (;;) {
    x[i] = '0' + i;
    if (++i == 4) {
        x[i] = '\0'; /* terminate string with null byte */
        printf("%s\n", x);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the contents is not undefined and this is not undefined behavior, the correct term in C is indeterminate value. In contrast to undefined behavior, this only gives you garbage values (`char` rarely has trap representations), but wouldn't eat your harddisk.

Comment: @JensGustedt you're right, I corrected the answer and added a reference to the standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of block scope. The loop body is a block, denoted by `{}`, which is entered and left in every loop iteration. Every time the block is entered, you get (conceptually) a new `x` with unspecified contents.

Since you've only set `x[3] = '3'` and `x[4] = '\0'` in the iteration where `printf` is called, only those two array members have well-defined content. The rest may contain anything, including `'\0'`, so `printf` may output any string of length at most 2, optionally followed by any other character and `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This would output as expected (a random character array), as an auto-variable is cleaned up after the scope in which it is declared terminates. To fix, move `x` outside of the scope of the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't see how your answer relates to his question. The `printf` is inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I think Richard is referring to the observation that the variable contents changes during iteration.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, but `x` is not. Every iteration of the loop, the stack can be cleaned up, in which case, `x` is deallocated.

Comment: `x` is not inside the `for` loop?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It is in the for-loop body as described in my question.

Answer (score -1):

The array will be allocated memory for each iteration and it will have the value gained in the last iteration only.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, or how it adds anything to the existing answers.